# monitor host machine using metricbeat system module from inside a docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, metricbeat

I'm using the docker-compose to configure the system module of Metricbeat  I have created the `metricbeat.yml` and `system.yml` and mount in my docker compose file

ex:

```
/opt/prism/config/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
```

but while restart the container I'm getting an error of

```
Exiting: error initializing publisher: error initializing processors: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.22/containers/json?limit=0: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: What does your `docker-compose.yml` look like? By default, the docker socket isn't going to be available inside a container.

Comment: If you're trying to monitor the host system, running the monitoring tool inside an isolation layer like Docker probably isn't what you want: you won't be able to see the host system's actual network interfaces, other processes, log files, _etc._

Comment: You need to add docker-compose file here, and also is dockerd service running?

Comment: Heyy folks thanks for response  that  issue is i want to monitor my host system using metricbeat  i am using a docker compose file to configure the Elastic kibana and metric beat  .  i have a question like can  i access the host machine system info from docker container using metric beat and load the logs into kibana dashboard i am following below link --  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-docker.html  --  i did the changes accordingly

Comment: metricbeat-host:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.8.9
    volumes:
      - /proc:/hostfs/proc:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /:/hostfs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
#      - /opt/prism/config/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:ro
#      - /opt/prism/config/metricbeat/modules.d/:/usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d/
    environment:
      system.hostfs: /hostfs
      network_mode: host using this my docker service is running but

Comment: @Er.Garvesh You need to edit your original post and put the entire contents of your docker compose file in there in code format using ''' code '''    I'm pretty sure I can help, just format the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you did not format the docker-compose.yml file correctly in the way in which you mount the docker socket.

Also it helps to run the conainer as root user.

```
version: '3.9'
  services:
    filebeat:
      image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.15.2
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        - "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200"
      volumes:
        - ./monitor/filebeat/filebeat.docker.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
        - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        - /home/docker-data/filebeat:/usr/share/filebeat/data
        - /home/docker-log:/usr/share/docker-log
       
      user: root
```

This is what I have, unfortunately this setup reports the stats of the container as I've only configured the docker module, if you configure the system module correctly, this should work.

It will certainly solve your permissions problem.